# STORAGE application( stock app) crashing (in android EMULATOR)

Tags: android, android-emulator

When I try to open the **Storage** from **Settings menu** in the emulator, it(always) crashes with following logcat-output

```
java.lang.NullPointerException at com.android.settings.deviceinfo.StorageVolumePreferenceCategory.updatePreferencesFromState(StorageVolumePreferenceCategory.java:238)
```

Here are the details of my AVD:

```
Name: Mx
Path: /home/vvy/.android/avd/Mx.avd
Target: Android 4.2.2 (API level 17)
ABI: armeabi-v7a
Skin: 480x800
Sdcard: /home/vvy/Documents/ANDU/sdC.img
________________________________________
hw.dpad: no
avd.ini.encoding: ISO-8859-1
disk.dataPartition.size: 200M
hw.gpu.enabled: yes
hw.cpu.model: cortex-a8
hw.ramSize: 512
hw.sdCard: yes
hw.device.name: Nexus One
vm.heapSize: 32
```

Note that I am able to upload data to SDCard from eclipse DDMS perspective, and the stock GALLERY application is able to show the image contents that are pushed via DDMS perspective.

Is this a known issue ? or I am doing something wrong ?

-----------------UPDATE-------------

Relevant logcat output

```
05-31 09:11:42.280: D/StorageMeasurement(2117): getDirectorySize(/mnt/sdcard/Alarms) returned 1536

05-31 09:11:42.340: D/StorageMeasurement(2117): getDirectorySize(/mnt/sdcard/Music) returned 1536


05-31 09:11:42.400: I/ActivityManager(287): Displayed com.android.settings/.SubSettings: +2s386ms


05-31 09:11:42.560: D/AndroidRuntime(2117): Shutting down VM


05-31 09:11:42.560: W/dalvikvm(2117): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)


05-31 09:11:42.611: D/StorageMeasurement(2117): getDirectorySize(/mnt/sdcard/Notifications) returned 1536


05-31 09:11:42.671: E/AndroidRuntime(2117): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

05-31 09:11:42.671: E/AndroidRuntime(2117): java.lang.NullPointerException

05-31 09:11:42.671: E/AndroidRuntime(2117):     at com.android.settings.deviceinfo.StorageVolumePreferenceCategory.updatePreferencesFromState(StorageVolumePreferenceCategory.java:238)

05-31 09:11:42.671: E/AndroidRuntime(2117):     at com.android.settings.deviceinfo.StorageVolumePreferenceCategory.updateApproximate(StorageVolumePreferenceCategory.java:307)

05-31 09:11:42.671: E/AndroidRuntime(2117):     at com.android.settings.deviceinfo.StorageVolumePreferenceCategory$1.handleMessage(StorageVolumePreferenceCategory.java:91)

05-31 09:11:42.671: E/AndroidRuntime(2117):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)

05-31 09:11:42.671: E/AndroidRuntime(2117):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)

05-31 09:11:42.671: E/AndroidRuntime(2117):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)

05-31 09:11:42.671: E/AndroidRuntime(2117):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

05-31 09:11:42.671: E/AndroidRuntime(2117):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)

05-31 09:11:42.671: E/AndroidRuntime(2117):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)

05-31 09:11:42.671: E/AndroidRuntime(2117):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)

05-31 09:11:42.671: E/AndroidRuntime(2117):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

05-31 09:11:42.761: W/ActivityManager(287):   Force finishing activity com.android.settings/.SubSettings

05-31 09:11:42.801: D/StorageMeasurement(2117): getDirectorySize(/mnt/sdcard/Pictures) returned 1536

05-31 09:11:42.801: D/StorageMeasurement(2117): getDirectorySize(/mnt/sdcard/Download) returned 1536

05-31 09:11:42.841: D/StorageMeasurement(2117): getDirectorySize(/mnt/sdcard) returned 14941696

05-31 09:11:42.921: W/ActivityManager(287):   Force finishing activity com.android.settings/.Settings
```

*UPDATE*

**Can someone tell me if they got the stock STORAGE application working in(emulator) android 4.2.2**

*Storage App does works fine on android 2.3.7 image(on emulator) though ! And I haven't found a solution yet*

*UPDATE*

Doesn't works with x86 image as well. I tried on LinuxMint13 and Win7 both.

Comment: The same thing happens to me - NULL pointer exception when accessing Settings...Storage. I am also able to upload via DDMS, but can't install an app to SDCard using:  android:installLocation="preferExternal" in AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: I am also stuck with same problem. Is it a open-source bug ? or we can tackle it in any ways ? Actually I need to format and erase my emulator's sdcard since the emulator is showing me "Your sdcard is full" I tried by moviing to Settings --> Storage --> "Erase SD Card" but in storage option itself it gets crashed with your above mentioned error. Any ideas.

Comment: @MohammedFirnaz You can delete the contents of memory card using the *adb* interface or from the *DDMS* perspective in eclipse. There is one more method; you can load the *sd card image* (.android/avd/name_of_AVD/sdcard.img) using a *third party software* and Delete contents from there.